# Broadcom WiFi driver problem

Tags: drivers, wireless, software-installation, broadcom

I had Ubuntu 15 in my hp laptop and had upgraded to 16.4 recently. I used  `bcmwl-kernel-source` to install the driver as I had done for 15, but `iwconfig` returns no wireless extensions. My adapter number is `broadcom[14e4:4365] rev 1`. 
product id is BCM43142 802.11b/g/n

```
$ sudo dpkg -s ...
Package: bcmwl-kernel-source 
Status: install OK installed
Section: admin 
...
Replaces: bcmwl - modaliases 
Depends: dkms,Linux - libc- Dev, libc6 - Dev 
Conflicts: bcmwl - modaliases 
...
$ sudo modprobe wl.... 
Modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': required key not available
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the results of these terminal commands: `sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source` and also: `sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl` Welcome to askubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your exact name of your nic by using command `lshw` and search for `network` section. You will find some thing like this :
`description: Network controller//product: BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n`
And try to download fixed bug or right driver of your nic.

Comment: I did that already as mentioned in ask Ubuntu and it did work for Ubuntu 15.  It's the update that's a problem. I've posted the nic for reference. Thanks for the input!